# MySQL stored procedure output issue for a particular query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a query for my final year project that would allow me to identify whether students prefer modules in a university degree with less exam weighting. I got help from someone and he suggested that I could use MySQL stored procedures to do that query.

Here is what I got so far:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE ModuleExamWeight()

BEGIN 

   DECLARE EnrollmentCount INT Default 0; 
   --DECLARE Outputresult varchar(255) DEFAULT ""; 

   --DECLARE output1 INT Default 0; 

   --DECLARE output2 INT Default 0; 

   DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT 0;

   DECLARE Clist varchar(255) DEFAULT "";


   DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT MODULEID FROM Modules ORDER BY Examweight; 


-- declare NOT FOUND handler

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

-- open module cursor
   OPEN c1; 

-- loop through module cursor by getting the number of enrollments per module

MODULES_LIST : LOOP 

FETCH c1 INTO Clist; 

SELECT ModuleID, COUNT(StudentID) INTO EnrollmentCount FROM ModuleEnrollment; 

IF finished = 1 THEN 
 LEAVE MODULES_LIST;
 END IF;


END LOOP MODULES_LIST;

CLOSE c1; 

-- This is like my first idea which doesn't work in order to print out the results.

-- SELECT ModuleID, ExamWeight, @EnrollmentCount FROM ModuleEnrollment; 


END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Basically I want to print out the result of this query such as this:

- Display  ModuleID for each module
- Display  Exam Weighting for them
- Display the values of the enrollment count variable for them.

However, I do not know how do that in a MySQL stored procedure.It would be nice if someone could help me on that. Thank you. I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: You are working on your *final* project and you don't know how to do a `JOIN`?

Comment: I know how to use a join but I'm thinking of  how I would write that for this particular query.

Comment: Interesting that no one got an answer, hope my question was clear.